Need understanding of Oracle FETCH
Lets say I have a result set from a query that comprises of 50 million records. Does adding a FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY clause, limit the query from building the result set of 50 million records? For example, the query will only build a result set of 100 records and return it? Or will the query still need to build a result set of 50 million records, and then only return the first 50 rows from it?
Just trying to understand the mechanics of using the FECTH clause.

If you look at the execution plans of queries you'll notice the engine typically tries to choose pipelined operators, rather than materialized ones. There are exceptions to this rule but you'll see more often than not that few parts of a query, if any, are materialized.
Now, when a step in the execution plan materializes a result, that means that all 50 million rows are processed in that step. Even if the next step only needs 100 rows, the previous one already performed a huge work.
On the other hand, if a step in the execution plan is pipelined then each row is handed to the next operator one at a time (at least conceptually, safe for buffering). This means that if the operator #1 was instructed to read 50 million rows, and then operator #2 limits to 100 rows, then operator #2 will inform back to operator #1 that its job is complete when it receives row #100; even if there are still 49,999,900 rows to go operator #1 had been informed to stop and won't continue processing any more rows. That means, the pipelined operator #1 is effectively short-circuited and stopped after the 100th row.
In short, materialization will always incurr in the whole cost before checking the next step, while pipelining won't.

For example, the query will only build a result set of 100 records and return it? Or will the query still need to build a result set of 50 million records, and then only return the first 50 rows from it?

If the limiting happens after any materialized operator, then yes, the engine will build an intermediate result set of 50 million rows, only to discard it pretty much entirely in the next step(s).

Thank you for explaining this. I will check the execution plan of the query.

From my point of view, it depends. On what? You, mostly.
Presume you want to fetch the first 100 rows from that 50 million rows table using such a statement:
select *
from citizens
fetch first 100 rows only;

It'll return any 100 rows and will be fast. Basically, it is similar to
select *
from citizens
where rownum <= 100;

which doesn't return rows in any particular order and - if table is affected by various DML statements (inserts, deletes) - that query will produce different results every time you run it.

If you modify it so that you get some kind of meaningful data set (for example, sorted by age), you'd add order by clause:
select *
from citizens
order by date_of_birth
fetch first 100 rows only;

Here it comes - that depends on you:

if date_of_birth column isn't indexed, Oracle will have to sort all 50 million rows to know which 100 to return, and that might (and probably will) be time consuming, unless there's some "shortcut" in optimizer I don't know about
if that column is indexed, fetch will be way faster.

See what explain plan says for different options you use, with and without indexes. Don't test on small table (such as Scott's EMP which has only 14 rows; full table scan on such a table doesn't take any longer than indexed scan).

Using the row limiting clause FETCH syntax will likely cause Oracle to create an execution plan that builds smaller intermediate result sets, which will likely favor the immediate response time over the time to fetch all records.
The Impaler mentioned materialization, which can be a useful way of thinking about operations. But as far as I know, Oracle's cost based optimizer does not by default make any effort to choose pipelined operators over materialized operators. Minimizing the cost to return the entire result set is the goal, not the time it takes to return the first row. However, the optimizer can be changed to prefer a fast response time by using a hint like /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ A row limiting FETCH can often have a similar affect and change the optimizer's decisions.
For example, one of the most common decisions the optimizer makes is whether to perform a join as a nested loop with index access, or a hash join with full table scans. Typically, nested loops and indexes are faster when the join returns a small percentage of data, and hash join and full table scans are faster when the join returns a large percentage of data. But the example below shows how FETCH can change that behavior to always favor a faster-responding nested loops and indexes.
Sample Schema - two large-ish tables of monotonically increasing numbers with an index.
--drop table test1 purge;
--drop table test2 purge;

create table test1(a number not null, b number) nologging;
insert /*+ append */ into test1 select level, level from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
create index test1_idx on test1(a);

create table test2(a number not null, b number) nologging;
insert /*+ append */ into test2 select level, level from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
create index test2_idx on test2(a);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST1');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST2');
end;
/

Default join is hash and full table scan
explain plan for
select *
from test1
join test2
    on test1.a = test2.a;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 497311279
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |  1000K|    19M|       |  3284   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |       |  1000K|    19M|    20M|  3284   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST1 |  1000K|  9765K|       |   588   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST2 |  1000K|  9765K|       |   588   (3)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("TEST1"."A"="TEST2"."A")
 
Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan

FETCH changes plan to use nested loops and indexes
explain plan for
select *
from test1
join test2
    on test1.a = test2.a
fetch first 100 rows only;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1069250624
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |           |   100 |  6500 |   302   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                          |           |   100 |  6500 |   302   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY        |           |   100 |  2000 |   302   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |           |   100 |  2000 |   302   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS               |           |   100 |  2000 |   302   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TEST1     |  1000K|  9765K|     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TEST2_IDX |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST2     |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_004"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=100)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY  NULL )<=100)
   6 - access("TEST1"."A"="TEST2"."A")

Even your bad decisions may improve
As Littlefoot explained, asking Oracle to perform an operation that requires processing all the rows, like ordering the results, may cause problems. However, there does appear to be a "shortcut" in the optimizer that can reduce sorting time.
The below query displays and sorts a single column of data. Notice the overall "Cost" estimate of 2244.
explain plan for
select a
from test1
order by a;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 840100365
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |           |  1000K|  4882K|  2244   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | TEST1_IDX |  1000K|  4882K|  2244   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Adding the fetch adds some new operations - a VIEW and a WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY. In this query, the data is already sorted in the index, so Oracle just needs to stop walking the index at the right moment. The total cost now decreases from 2244 to 3.
explain plan for
select a
from test1
order by a
fetch first 100 rows only;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 2868844267
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           |   100 |  3900 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |           |   100 |  3900 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY|           |   100 |   500 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN     | TEST1_IDX |  1000K|  4882K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=100)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "A")<=100)

FETCH won't fix all your performance problems, but it's worth adding that clause to improve performance when you only need the first rows.
